# Связать событие Filereader().onprogress с множественными элементами progress

Tags: javascript, html5

В проекте есть загрузчик картинок с "превьюшками" и есть несколько элементов `progress` для отображения процесса загрузки по каждой картинке отдельно. Но приведенный код отображает прогресс только на последнем, созданном элементе `progress`. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы процесс загрузки каждой картинки отображался в соответствующем элементе `progress`?

function processFiles(files) {
    var numFiles = files.length;

```
for (var i = 0, numFiles = files.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
    var f = files[i];

  // Обрабатываем только графические файлы !
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

 //Проверяем существует ли элемент img если нет то запишем следующую картинку в него
 for (var e = 0; e < image_amount_restriction; e++) 
 {
     if (document.getElementById("img"+e)==null) 
     {
         element_id=e;
         break;
     }
}

var last = image_amount_restriction - element_id;
console.log(last);
if ( last < 2) {return false;}



//создем обьекты UI
 var parent = document.getElementById("photos");
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.id = ("block"+element_id);
 div.className  = "editbox";

 parent.appendChild(div);

 var parentE2 = document.getElementById("block"+element_id);
 var edit_panel = document.createElement("span");
 edit_panel.className = "edit_panel";
 edit_panel.id = ("edit_panel"+element_id);

 var hiddenfield = document.createElement("input");
 hiddenfield.type = "hidden";
 hiddenfield.name ="output[]";
 hiddenfield.id =("out"+element_id);

 parentE2.appendChild(hiddenfield);

 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.classList.add("obj");
 img.id = ("img"+element_id);

 parentE2.appendChild(edit_panel);
 parentE2.appendChild(img);

 //прогрессбар
 var progressbar = document.createElement("progress");
 progressbar.id = ("my-progress"+element_id);
 progressbar.className = "progressbar";
 parentE2.appendChild(progressbar);

 var parentE3 = document.getElementById("edit_panel"+element_id);
 var trash_can = document.createElement("a");
 trash_can.className = "foto_n1";
 trash_can.id = element_id;
 trash_can.href = "#";
 trash_can.onclick = remove;

 parentE3.appendChild(trash_can);



 var reader = new FileReader();

//Недоделанный прогрессбар! 
reader.onprogress = function(event) 
{

if (event.lengthComputable) 
    {
        console.log(progressbar.id);
        progressbar.max = event.total;
        progressbar.value = event.loaded;   
    }
}

reader.onloadend = function(event) 
{
    var contents = event.target.result,
    error = event.target.error;
    if (error != null) 
    {
        console.error("File could not be read! Code " + error.code);
    } 
    else 
    {
        progressbar.max = 1;
        progressbar.value = 1;
     }
    }



 // Пишем картинки после загрузки в соответсвующие контейнеры
 reader.onload = (function(aImg,hiddenfield,progressbar) 
 {
     return function(e) 
     { 
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
        hiddenfield.value=e.target.result;
        //когда загрузились, скрываем прогресс бар
        progressbar.className += " hidden";
    }; 
})
(img,hiddenfield,progressbar);

  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь [принятой практики  в отношении приветствий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7).

Comment: приведите код полностью. не хватает информации

Comment: в определении `progressbar.id = ("my-progress"+element_id);` откуда element_id значение?

Comment: у вас в определении события `reader.onload` используется замыкание при этом в определении `reader.onprogress` нет, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что не использовано замыкание при привязке обработчика. Т.к. не видно необходимого кода, то попробую посоветовать "на глаз":

```
        for (i=0; i<arFiles.length; i++){       
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener('progress', (function(i){
                                                return function(event){ progressHook(event, i) }
                                            })(i) );
        ...
            reader.readAsDataURL(arFiles[i]);
        }
```

В функцию `progressHook(event, i)` первым параметром передаётся событие, а вторым - порядковый номер файла, прогресс, которого хотите отслеживать.

Comment: Благодарю - направили в правильное русло.